# Displaying two methods in a pipeline

Tags: powershell, office365

I have this oneliner that will translate an Outlook 365 calendars bookinpolicy from x.500 format to the actual human readable name:

```
((Get-CalendarProcessing dept-calendar-*).BookInPolicy | Get-DistributionGroup).name
```

What I can't figure out is how to also display the original calendar name as well?  Right now I get the names, but no reference to what calendar it belongs to, such as:

```
dept-calendar-bookinpolicy-mgr
dept-calendar-bookinpolicy25-mgr
dept-calendar-bookinpolicy98-mgr
```

I would like it to look something more like this:

```
dept-calendar-room1
dept-calendar-bookinpolicy-mgr

dept-calendar-room6
dept-calendar-bookinpolicy25-mgr

dept-calendar-room8
dept-calendar-bookinpolicy98-mgr
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing in parentheses is like using a `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` so you'll have to insert a ForEach-Object

```
Get-CalendarProcessing dept-calendar-* | ForEach-Object{
   $_.BookInPolicy
  ($_.BookInPolicy | Get-DistributionGroup).Name
  ""
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run that:
`The pipeline was not run because a pipeline is already running. Pipelines cannot be run concurrently.`
    `+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Microsoft.Power...tHelperRunspace:ExecutionCmdletHelperRunspace) [], PSInvalidOperationException`
    `+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotePipelineExecutionFailed`
But, I do get the calendar name this time.

Comment: Sorry, seems something special to those cmdlets I can't test here. You could try `$_.BookInPolicy | Get-DistributionGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: Still getting a similar error.  Thanks for the ideas though.

Comment: what if you remove the second pipeline like this? `(Get-DistributionGroup $_.BookInPolicy).name`

Answer (score 0):

With a little more help on my end I was able to figure out a way to do this, so I thought I'd answer my own question:

```
(Get-CalendarProcessing dept-calendar-*) | ForEach-Object { $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty "BookInPolicy_Group" "" -Force; if(-not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.BookInPolicy)){$_.BookInPolicy_Group = ($_.BookInPolicy | Get-DistributionGroup).Name} Write-Output $_} | Select-Object Identity,BookInPolicy_Group | Format-List
```

I was able to get what I wanted with the above.

```
Identity           : dept-calendar-room1
BookInPolicy_Group : dept-calendar-bookinpolicy-mgr

Identity           : dept-calendar-room6
BookInPolicy_Group : dept-calendar-bookinpolicy25-mgr

Identity           : dept-calendar-room8
BookInPolicy_Group : dept-calendar-bookinpolicy98-mgr
```

Hopefully this will help the next person.